# Elasticseach wildcard query on nested types

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to run a wildcard query on a nested type in ElasticSearch.  I have records with the following structure:

```
{
  "field_1": "value_1",
  "nested_field_1": [
    {
      "field_type": "some_field_type",
      "field_value": "some_value"
    },
    {
      "field_type": "another_field_type",
      "field_value": "another_value"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to run wildcard query on the nested_field, either on `field_value` or on `field_type`.

I can query for an exact match with this syntax:

```
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "nested_field_1",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "nested_field_1.field_value": "another_value"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But replacing the `match` with `wildcard` doesn't yield any results.
Any help would be welcome.

Comment: can you show your wildcard query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just tried your example and it gives me the result and used [elasticsearch official wildcard query doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html).

### Index Def

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "field_1": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "nested_field_1" :{
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                    "field_type" :{
                        "type" : "text"
                    },
                    "field_value" :{
                        "type" : "integer" --> created as interfere field
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index doc

```
{
    "field_1": "value_1",
    "nested_field_1": [
        {
            "field_type": "some_field_type",
            "field_value": 20
        },
        {
            "field_type": "another_field_type",
            "field_value": 40
        }
    ]
}
```

### Wildcard search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "nested_field_1",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "wildcard": { --> note 
                                "nested_field_1.field_type": {
                                    "value": "another_field_type"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search result

```
  "nested_field_1": [
                        {
                            "field_type": "some_field_type",
                            "field_value": 20
                        },
                        {
                            "field_type": "another_field_type",
                            "field_value": 40
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Comment: Is the fact that `field_value` is defined to be an `integer` important? In my actual case, `field_type` is defined to be a `keyword` and `field_value` is `text`.
Running your query on the `keyword` field works, but running it on `text` doesn't return results.

Comment: you didn't provide the mapping, so I assumed it to integer, but this doesn't matter as we are searching on the `field_type` which is `text` and do you mean that you defined this to `keyword` and it doesn't work in that case?

Comment: apparently my problem was using uppercase letters when searching, when using all lowercase it works!

Comment: Great, glad it helped

Comment: btw if you use the `text` field, then it would be case-insenitive search as it uses the `standard` tokenizer which converts tokens to lowercase